# Timeouting subprocesses in Python

Tags: python, adb

```
def adbshell(command, serial=None, adbpath='adb'):
    args = [adbpath]
    if serial is not None:
        args.extend(['-s', serial])
    args.extend(['shell', command])
    return subprocess.check_output(args)



def pmpath(serial=None, adbpath='adb'):
    return adbshell('am instrument -e class............', serial=serial, adbpath=adbpath)
```

I have to run this test for a specific time period, and then exit if it is not working. How do I provide a timeout?

Answer (score 1):

Depending which Python version you are running.

**Python 3.3 onwards:**

`subprocess.check_output()` provides a `timeout` param. Check the signature [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, universal_newlines=False, timeout=None)
```

**Below Python 3.3:**

You can use `threading` module. Something like:

```
def run(args, timeout):
    def target():
        print 'Start thread'
        subprocess.check_output(args)
        print 'End thread'

    thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
    thread.start() # Start executing the target()

    thread.join(timeout) # Join the thread after specified timeout
```

Note - I haven't tested the code above with `threading` and `check_output()`. Normally I use the `subprocess.Popen()` which offers more flexibility and handles almost all scenarios. Check the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

The `Popen` constructure provides more flexiblity, as it can be used to check the exit status of the `subprocess` call.

The `Popen.poll` returns `None` if the process has not terminated yet. Hence call the subrprocess, `sleep` for the time required time out.

consider a simple `test.py` which is the subprocess called from the main program.

```
import time

for i in range(10):
        print i
        time.sleep(2)
```

The `test.py` is called from another program using the `subprocess.Popen`

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import time

cmd = Popen(['python','test.py'],stdout=PIPE)
print cmd.poll()
time.sleep(2)
if  cmd.poll()== None:
       print "killing"
       cmd.terminate()
```

`time.sleep(2)`

provides a time out of 2 seconds, so that the program can excecute.
checks the exit status of the process using `Popen.poll`

if `None`, the process has not terminated, kills the process.